# Nested Observables: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am subscribing to an observable and using the a property which is an array in the result to make calls and modify each item in the array and return the final result or output.

Below is my code that is not currently working. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
What should I change to make this code work?

```
    this.esService.search(JSON.stringify(query)).subscribe(response => {
        let temp;
        this.esResponse = response;
        let result = this.esResponse.hits.hits;
        return from(result).pipe(
            concatMap(item => 
            this.productService.getProductById(this.schemaId, item['_source']['consensusAssessmentId']).pipe(
                map(resp => {
                const answers = resp['answers'];
                const meets_count = answers.reduce((acc, cur) => cur.value === "Meets" ? ++acc : acc, 0);
                const needs_count = answers.reduce((acc, cur) => cur.value === "Needs Improvement" ? ++acc : acc, 0);
                item['_source']['meets'] = meets_count.toString();
                item['_source']['needs'] = needs_count.toString();
            })
        ))

        ).subscribe(resp => {
            temp = resp; 
            this.rows = temp.map(
                this.esService.convertToPE
            ); 
        })    


    })
```

This code seems to be working, but it's not efficient. I am providing it to better clarify my goal with the code.

```
    this.esService.search(JSON.stringify(query)).subscribe(response => {
        let temp = [];
        this.esResponse = response;
        let result = this.esResponse.hits.hits;
        result.forEach(item => {
            this.productService.getProductById(this.schemaId, item['_source']['consensusAssessmentId']).subscribe(resp => {
                const answers = resp['answers'];
                const meets_count = answers.reduce((acc, cur) => cur.value === "Meets" ? ++acc : acc, 0);
                const needs_count = answers.reduce((acc, cur) => cur.value === "Needs Improvement" ? ++acc : acc, 0);
                item['_source']['meets'] = meets_count.toString();
                item['_source']['needs'] = needs_count.toString();
            })
           temp.push(item);
        })          
        this.rows = temp.map(
            this.esService.convertToPE
        );

    });
```

Comment: the whole code should be changes, and instead of subscribing multiple times, you need to use flatMap or mergeMap

Comment: Your `map()` operator doesn't return a value, and you can not return a `subscribe()` unless you wished to return the subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I've got what you want to do, but I guess you want something like this:

```js
this.esService.search(JSON.stringify(query)).pipe(
  tap((response) => this.esResponse = response),
  switchMap((response) => {
    const arrayOfObservables: any[] = response.hits.hits.map((item) =>
      this.productService.getProductById(this.schemaId,
       item['_source']['consensusAssessmentId']).pipe(tap((resp) => {
          const answers = resp['answers'];
          const meets_count = answers.reduce((acc, cur) => cur.value === "Meets" ? ++acc : acc, 0);
          const needs_count = answers.reduce((acc, cur) => cur.value === "Needs Improvement" ? ++acc : acc, 0);
          item['_source']['meets'] = meets_count.toString();
          item['_source']['needs'] = needs_count.toString();
        }))
    );
    return forkJoin(arrayOfObservables);

  })).subscribe((resp) => this.rows = resp.map(
    this.esService.convertToPE));
```

Comment: I provide more info.

Comment: Based on your comments on @wentjun's answer, I modified my answer. Take a look. But what you need is a little bit blurry to me yet.

Comment: this.esResponse.hits.hits... is an array?

Comment: Yes, it is an array.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have some idea of how observables work, but let's make some changes to the way you approach your problem by simplifying your approach. First, instead of nesting/chaining multiple `subscribe()` methods, we make use of [pipeable operators](https://reactive.how/rxjs/pipeable-operators).

Then, we use RxJS's [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) operator to map over the observable values from `search()` into an inner observable which will be consumed by `getProductById()`.

Within the `mergeMap()` block, we will need to iterate through the array, represented by the constant variable `result`. We loop through every element in the `result` array, then we push each observable from `getProductById()` into the `observablesList`. Then, we use the [forkJoin()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) operator, which waits for the iterations to be completed before returning all the observables.

Do not forget to import the required operators into your class/component.

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.esService.search(JSON.stringify(query)).pipe(
    mergeMap(response => {
      this.esResponse = response;
      const result = this.esResponse.hits.hits;
      const observablesList = [];
      observablesList = result.map(obj => {
        const id = obj['_source']['consensusAssessmentId'];
        return this.productService.getProductById(this.schemaId, id);
      });
      return forkJoin(observablesList);
    })
  ).subscribe(resp => {
    console.log(resp);
     // handle the rest here
     const answers = resp['answers'];
     const meets_count = answers.reduce((acc, cur) => cur.value === "Meets" ? ++acc : acc, 0);
     const needs_count = answers.reduce((acc, cur) => cur.value === "Needs Improvement" ? ++acc : acc, 0);
     item['_source']['meets'] = meets_count.toString();
     item['_source']['needs'] = needs_count.toString();

     // more things
  })
});
```

Comment: `const result = this.esResponse.hits.hits;` returns an array. I need to loop through the array and get an `id` in each object (`['_source']['consensusAssessmentId']` to make this call `this.productService.getProductById(this.schemaId, result['_source']['consensusAssessmentId']);`

Comment: Ok, I have updated my code, to make use of forkJoin to handle the looping of the array

Comment: The variable `result` contains an array of objects which will be updated with new properties `meets` and `needs`. Your proposed solution doesn't allow to get the `result`.